# Como imprimir las horas dentro de un rango con un foreach en php

Tags: php, foreach

Tengo un array multidimensional, donde están guardadas las horas de esta forma, 01:00AM - 02:00AM - 03:00AM etc... luego tengo un selector donde se elije una hora de inicio y una hora final, es decir puedo seleccionar por ejemplo de 03:00AM hasta 08:00AM, entonces lo que deseo es que en la base de datos en un campo se me registren todas las horas desde las 03:00am hasta las 08:00am, es decir quedaría así 03 04 05 06 07 08 solamente las horas que están dentro de ese rango que hemos elegido.

Entonces en una variable llamada inicio **$inicio** he guardado el valor de la hora inicial ejemplo: 03:00am esto lo traigo desde el selector de hora, en otra variable tengo guardada la hora final **$fin**

Entonces recorro las horas con un foreach, el problema esta en que me repite las horas de la mañana y de la tarde, por ejemplo: de **3am** a **6am** me las registra, pero también me registra de **3pm** a **6pm** esto ocurre creo por la condición del **if()** que esta dentro del foreach, no se como hacer para que no se repita las horas, que solo me registre el rango deseado, si por ejemplo deseo, de 3am a 6am que no queden también registradas de 3pm a 6pm.

Dejo el código por si me ayudan con esto y gracias!

````
                                   1=>array(1=>"01:00AM"),
                                   2=>array(2=>"02:00AM"),
                                   3=>array(3=>"03:00AM"),
                                   4=>array(4=>"04:00AM"),
                                   5=>array(5=>"05:00AM"),
                                   6=>array(6=>"06:00AM"),
                                   7=>array(7=>"07:00AM"),
                                   8=>array(8=>"08:00AM"),
                                   9=>array(9=>"09:00AM"),
                                 10=>array(10=>"10:00AM"),
                                 11=>array(11=>"11:00AM"),
                                 12=>array(12=>"12:00PM"), 
                                 13=>array(13=>"01:00PM"),
                                 14=>array(14=>"02:00PM"),
                                 15=>array(15=>"03:00PM"),
                                 16=>array(16=>"04:00PM"),
                                 17=>array(17=>"05:00PM"),
                                 18=>array(18=>"06:00PM"),
                                 19=>array(19=>"07:00PM"),
                                 20=>array(20=>"08:00PM"),
                                 21=>array(21=>"09:00PM"),
                                 22=>array(22=>"10:00PM"), 
                                 23=>array(23=>"11:00PM"));  


$nuevoFormato = '';
$inicio = $lunesdesde;
$fin    = $luneshasta;


foreach($horario as $grupo) {
    foreach($grupo as $status) {
       
        $nuevoFormato = $status;
        
        if($nuevoFormato >= $inicio && $nuevoFormato <= $fin) {
         
          // Pasamos todos los datos a $contenido
            $contenido.= $status.PHP_EOL;
                                      
            
                }// fin del if

          }// fin del foreach
     }// fin del foreach ```
````

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la necesidad de un array de arrays. ¿No te basta un array solo y quedarte con los indices que haya entre inicio y fin dado que no almacenas el contenido referenciado por esos índices? ¿Podrias indicar exactamente qué hay dentro de $horario?

Comment: Ciertamente no veo la necesidad de arreglo multidimensional para las horas. Di una respuesta con base a lo que tienes en el foreach.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres guardar algo que podría generarse de forma dinámica con una facilidad asombrosa? PHP (como cualquier otro lenguaje) tiene clases de intervalos con los que podrías generar rangos de horas, fechas, períodos, etc dinámicamente. Es decir, guardarías la hora de inicio, la hora de fin y a partir de ellas podrás generar los intervalos que sean requeridos entre esos dos valores. Revisa por ejemplo [la clase `Interval`de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una subcadena de la hora, tomando el AM usando la función substr()

Por ejemplo,

`$tiempo1 = substr($inicio, -2)`, de esta forma te devuelve el AM o PM de la hora y la puedes usar en tu condicional.

````
foreach($horario as $grupo) {
    foreach($grupo as $status) {
       
        $nuevoFormato = $status;
        $tiempo2 = substr($nuevoFormato, -2)
        if($nuevoFormato >= $inicio && $nuevoFormato <= $fin) && $tiempo1 = $tiempo2{
         
          // Pasamos todos los datos a $contenido
            $contenido.= $status.PHP_EOL;
                                      
            
                }// fin del if

          }// fin del foreach
     }// fin del foreach ```
````